# File tokenization in java

Tags: java, tokenize

The below code is for tokenization in java. I am having a small bug which I am just not able to fix. This is regarding file tokenization. In this code, if a user enters four capital words in a file. It is not supposed to be tokenised and is supposed to be retained at the same line. The rest of the words have to be tokenized if there is no capital letter or anything.

For example

> United States Of America
>   Hi I am Walt.

The O/P is supposed to look like this below.

> United States Of America
>
> Hi
>
> I
>
> am
>
> Walt.

This is how it's supposed to look like. After I wrote my code I am facing a small bug.
The O/P is showing up like this.

> United States Of America
>
> States
>
> Of
>
> America
>
> Hi
>
> I
>
> am
>
> Walt.

Basically I need to get rid of "States Of America". In the piece of code where I am checking for uppercase. Could you please help me in solving this problem, as I am just not able to get my around it? Anything to make this possible will be helpful.

Please feel free to alter my code and try getting my output.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Tokenize {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
      BufferedReader inputReader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Advait/Desktop/nlp_wikipedia.txt"));
      String currentLine;
      while ((currentLine = inputReader.readLine())!=null) {
      // START STUDENT CODE
        char atUpper;
        char atUpper1;
        int keeper = 1;
        int keeper1 = 0;
        String temp = "";
        int j;
        int i;
        int counter = 0;
        int m=0;
        int n=0;
        String temp1 = "";
        boolean boolKeeper,boolKeeper1;
        String Delimeter = "[\\s,:;'!?()\"]+";
        for(j=0;j<(currentLine.length()-1);j++) {
          if(currentLine.contains("://")) {
            currentLine=currentLine.replace("://","#");
          }
        }
        String token1[] = currentLine.split(Delimeter);
        for(j=0;j<(token1.length)-1;j++) {
          if(j>0) {
            if(keeper==0) {
              atUpper = token1[j+1].charAt(0);
              atUpper1 = token1[keeper].charAt(0);
              boolKeeper = Character.isUpperCase(atUpper);
              boolKeeper1 = Character.isUpperCase(atUpper1);
              if(boolKeeper==true && boolKeeper1==true) {
                m++;
                temp1 = token1[keeper].concat(" ").concat(token1[j+1]);
                token1[keeper] = temp1;
              }
            } else {
              i=j+1;
              atUpper = token1[j].charAt(0);
              atUpper1 = token1[i].charAt(0);
              boolKeeper = Character.isUpperCase(atUpper);
              boolKeeper1 = Character.isUpperCase(atUpper1);
              if(boolKeeper==true && boolKeeper1==true) {
                counter=counter+1;
                if(counter == 1) {
                  keeper1 = j;
                }
                n++;
                temp = token1[keeper1].concat(" ").concat(token1[i]);
                token1[keeper1] = temp;
              }
            }
          } else {
            i=j+1;
            atUpper = token1[j].charAt(0);
            atUpper1 = token1[i].charAt(0);
            boolKeeper = Character.isUpperCase(atUpper);
            boolKeeper1 = Character.isUpperCase(atUpper1);
            if(boolKeeper==true && boolKeeper1==true) {
              keeper = 0;
              m++;
              temp = token1[j].concat(" ").concat(token1[i]);
              token1[j] = temp;
            }
          }
          ArrayList<String> LineList = new ArrayList<String>();
          for (String token : token1) {
            if (!token.equals("%")) {
              LineList.add(token);
            }
          }
          token1 = LineList.toArray(new String[LineList.size()]);
          String token2 = token1[j];
          for (int l=0;l<(token2.length()-1);l++) {
            if(token2.charAt(l) == '-' && token2.charAt(l+1) == '\n') {
              String token3[] = token2.split("-");
              token1[j] = token3[0] + token3[1];
            }
          }
        }
        for(int k=0;k<(token1.length);k++) {
          if(token1[k].contains(".") && token1[k].contains("@")) {
            token1[k] = token1[k].replace(".", "*");
          }
          if(token1[k].contains("#") && token1[k].contains(".")) {
            token1[k] = token1[k].replace("#","://");
            token1[k] = token1[k].replace(".","*");
          }
        }
        for(int k=0;k<(token1.length);k++) {
          StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(token1[k],".");
          while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            token1[k] = st.nextToken();
          }
        }
        for(int k=0;k<(token1.length);k++) {
          String token4 = token1[k];
          for (int l=0;l<(token4.length()-1);l++) {
            if(token4.contains("@") && token4.contains("*")) {
              token1[k] = token4.replace("*",".");
            }
            if(token1[k].contains("://") && token1[k].contains("*")) {
              token1[k] = token4.replace("*",".");
            }
          }
        }
        for(int k=0;k<(token1.length);k++) {
          System.out.println(token1[k]);
        }
        // END STUDENT CODE
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Caught IOException: "+e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So somewhere in that 200+ lines of code is the section we're supposed to look at?

Comment: NOTE TO ANSWERERS: this is homework and it is not appropriate to give full solutions, only hints.

Comment: Focus your code to just the [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) we need to solve the problem.

Comment: It would help if you commented the code to make it more understandable.

Comment: Probably you have a bug in incrementing any counter.
After it has found 'United States Of America' the algorithm has to continue at word number 5 and not at word number 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you are cramming everything into a single huge function. You need to split the code into meaningful units that each perform a well-defined, easily-understood operation. For the specific issue of capitalized words, I recommend a function `int capitalizedWordStreakLength(String[] tokens, int i)`. You can use that function in a loop that assembles a `List<String>` of resulting tokens by iterating over the `String[]` of your "raw" tokens and, if that function returns four or more, concats those words into a single token.